# Symfony 6.X, 7 - Ajax request xhr never ends in PHP 8.3

Tags: php, symfony, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem with Symfony 6.4, 7.0 and PHP 8.3.
Indeed, when I make an ajax POST request of type xhr it spins in the void infinitely. The PHP timeout does not seem to take it into account, so I have no errors and therefore no logs

[image: looog time]

What is strange is that when I switch back to PHP 8.2.13 or 8.1.26 I have no problem.
I think more of a configuration problem than a code one, yet I have the same configurations with PHP 8.2.13 and PHP 8.3.0

This is my work environment

[image: work environment]

My php configuration for php 8.3
[image: My php configuration]

Installed extensions for php 8.3

[image: Installed extensions for php 8.3]

My php configuration for php 8.2.13

[image: My php configuration for php 8.2.13]

Installed extensions for php 8.2.13

[image: Installed extensions for php 8.2.13]

What I tried

- Update wampserver in latest version 3.3.0 to 3.3.3
- Update from Apache 2.4.52.2 to 2.4.58
- Installing PHP 8.3 via the wamp installer
- Deleted my entire development environment and completely reinstalled wampserver 3.3.3 with the latest version of Apache and PHP

*sorry for my poor English*
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The PHP script is probably crashing. Check the PHP error log.

Comment: unfortunately there is no error because my ajax call never completes. ;(

The problem is that all of my ajax calls on my entire application do not work under PHP 8.3

Comment: But regular PHP pages work? That's weird.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the site works, only the ajax calls are in vain.

I also find this very weird and I don't understand what could be wrong
Thanks for your help anyway